# Passing Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables

I am a newbie to the confusing world of Ajax, I wanted to know if someone could help me format the line with comment on it correctly. The rest of the code works fine (but I abbreviated it here).

```
function xmlhttpcode () {

var1 = simple.of.Hello;

var2 = thing.because.World;


xmlhttpcode.open("GET","myfile.php?foo= + var1 +&bar= + var2",false); //this line

xmlhttpcode.send ()
```

Comment: what isn't working? What error do you get? Please tell us more about your issue. How did you get your `xmlhttpcode` from? -1

Comment: when joining strings with variables, use the something along the lines of: `"myfile.php?foo=" + var1 +"&bar="+var2"` - keep in mind that `var1` and `var2` would have unknown values since `simple.of.Hello;` is not a string literal and it makes no reference to an existing variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, that line should be formatted as so:

```
xmlhttpcode.open("GET","myfile.php?foo=" + var1 + "&bar=" + var2,false); //this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test your AJAX call but the String concatenation can be done like this:

```js
function xmlhttpcode() {
    var fooValue = "fooValueOfOne";
    var barValue = "barValueOfTwo";

    var url = "myfile.php?foo=" + fooValue + "&bar=" + barValue;

    // verify your URL prints as desired
    alert(url);
}

xmlhttpcode();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just needed help with correct syntax, and everything is working fine now  :)